# Looking for POSIX utility to test whether filename is a symlink

Tags: symlink, posix

I know that some shells at least support file test operators that detect when a filename names a symlink.

Is there a POSIX *utility*<sup>1</sup> that provides the same functionality?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I may not be using the right terminology here.  What I mean by "utility" is a free-standing executable living somewhere under `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc., as opposed to a shell built-in.</sup>

Comment: are you thinking about `file`  command ? see man file

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're looking for [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html):

> -h  pathname
>
> True if pathname resolves to a file that exists and is a symbolic link. False if pathname cannot be resolved, or if pathname resolves to a file that exists but is not a symbolic link. If the final component of pathname is a symlink, that symlink is not followed.

Most shells have it as a builtin, but `test` also exists as a standalone program, which can be called from other programs without invoking an intermediate shell. This is the case for most builtins that shells may have, except for those that act on the shell itself (special builtins like `break`, `export`, `set`, …).

`[ -h pathname ]` is equivalent to `test -h pathname`; `[` works in exactly the same way as `test`, except that `[` requires an extra `]` argument at the end. `[`, like `test`, exists as a standalone program.

For example:

```
$ ln -s foo bar
$ /usr/bin/test -h bar && echo y
y
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the solution you propose is failing to tell that the "filename names a symlink" when the symlink does not resolve to a file that exists.

Comment: @maxime.bochon I just tested it and it exits with 0 (successful), when the target of the symlink doesn't exist.

Comment: @maxime.bochon yes. The solution only deals with the specific file you are testing. It will tell you whether it is a link or not. Whether the target exists or not is something completely different. A broken link is still a link.

Comment: confirmed.  `mkdir a; ln -s a b; ln -s c d; test -h b && echo link; test -h c || echo notlink; test -h d && echo link` correctly outputs `link` `notlink` `link`

Answer (score 3):

Two utilities could do that for you, `file`and `readlink`:

1. `file some_symlink` will display `some_symlink: symbolic link to 'some_target'`
2. `readlink some_symlink` will exit with code 0 whereas `readlink some_file` will exit with code 1

Note that *exit code* is stored in variable `$?`, and can be displayed with `echo $?`.

Comment: Neither of these is in POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

There is also `stat`:

```
$ touch test
$ ln -s test test_l

$ stat test
  File: `test'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 4309        Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ vagrant)   Gid: ( 1000/ vagrant)
Access: 2015-09-11 11:37:59.864165922 +0000
Modify: 2015-09-11 11:37:59.864165922 +0000
Change: 2015-09-11 11:37:59.864165922 +0000
 Birth: -

$ stat test_l
  File: `test_l' -> `test'
  Size: 4           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 7179        Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/ vagrant)   Gid: ( 1000/ vagrant)
Access: 2015-09-11 11:38:07.220173955 +0000
Modify: 2015-09-11 11:38:07.220173955 +0000
Change: 2015-09-11 11:38:07.220173955 +0000
 Birth: -

$ stat -c "%F" test
regular empty file

$ stat -c "%F" test_l
symbolic link
```

Answer (score -2):

Alternatively you can use a simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash    
ls -alFQ | grep '^l'
```

The Unix mantra is to have small simple utilities that can be chained together to achieve complex task. So while this is technically not a POSIX utility, it's very close to one.

If you want to get fancy you can only select what portion of the string to return:

```
#!/bin/bash    
ls -alFQ | grep '^l' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 11
```

The `-f 11` returns the file the link is pointing to, and `-f 10` return the name of the link.
This only works if the files names have no spaces in them, otherwise it gets tricky - it can probably be done, but you'll have to escape the white spaces or use a pattern, which is more than I care to write at the moment.

If you want something that returns 0/1:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    if [[ -n $(ls -alFQ | grep '^l') ]]; then
        exit
    else
        exit 1
    fi
```

Comment: [Parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is, in general, a bad idea.  Unusual filenames can wreck all sorts of havoc on your attempts to interpret things.

Comment: You are right, having spaces in the file names will cause problems, I'll update my answer. It's probably doable if you use ls -b to escape the whitespaces, but then you'll have to cut it appropriately ...

Comment: It's not just spaces.  What if someone creates a file named `filename\nlrw-r--r--    1 root        wheel        43 Nov 10  2014 .htaccess`, ie. with a newline and a directory listing in the name?

Comment: This is beyond the original question, but yes it can be done safely, although some creative scripting / regex usage will be required. If you want to start another question I can go in more details there.

Comment: Having thoroughly tested your suggestions, your first one fails on filenames containing an "l" after a newline in their name, your second one fails on filenames with spaces, and your third (in addition to the filename issue) has the unfortunate side effect of logging the user out if run standalone.

Comment: 1. New lines and other non printable characters are not part of the POSIX portable character set for filenames and thus might not be supported. 2. Those are rarely if ever used. 3. This can be easily remedied by using ls' Q option. As I said, if you want me to elaborate, create a question.